# Reload Windows wallpaper after connection loss

Tags: windows, windows-10

Our Windows domain provides a wallpaper image via group policy. The image file is accessible through a network path.

If there is no network connection during client computer boot, the wallpaper will be black, because Windows couldn't access it. This sometimes happens if you use Wi-Fi connection and always with VPN.

Unfortunately Windows doesn't automatically try to load it again as soon as there the network connection is established.

How can I force Windows to reload the background image?

Comment: This is a different question! The linked question changed the image path. In my case the image path doesn't change. It's just not accesible at login time. The answer doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Havd you tried `RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1, True`?

Comment: Tried that already and didn't work